# MFC/Windows: How can drawing an icon be limited to a rectangle?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, icons, custom-controls

`CDC` methods like `DrawText()` take a rect argument that clips the text.

How can I clip drawing of a icon with `DrawIcon()` or `DrawIconEx()`?

Answer (score 0):

A clip region can be added temporarily to the CDC to achieve this.

```
      hiconMyIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon( IDI_MY_ICON );

      CRgn rgn;
      rgn.CreateRectRgnIndirect( &rect );
      pdc->SelectClipRgn( &rgn );
      pdc->DrawIcon( rect.left, rect.top, hiconMyIcon );
      // or if you want a specific size of icon:
      // DrawIconEx( pdc->GetSafeHdc(), rect.left, rect.top,
      //             hiconMyIcon, 16, 16, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL );
      pdc->SelectClipRgn( NULL );
```